# Ansible 2.9.8 - passing variable to ansible.cfg

Tags: ansible

Team,

We are maintaining multiple environments ansible config files. And the environment gets chosen in the ansible.cfg(`./ssh-{{ env }}.cfg`) based on the variable value(which passed through extra-vars). Which is working perfectly alright in 2.9.6 and in 2.9.8 the value is not getting passed.

I have tried  `./ssh-"{{ env }}".cfg` , `./ssh-\"{{ env }}\".cfg`, `./ssh-'{{ env }}'.cfg`, but nothing helped. Any suggestions?

```
ansible-playbook -b -u test-user -e 'ansible_ssh_pass=****' -e 'env=apac' -i inventory.yml l provisioning/packages-playbook.yml
```

ansible.cfg

```
+ cat ansible.cfg
[defaults]

host_key_checking = no
record_host_keys = no
timeout = 10
remote_tmp = /tmp/.ansible-${USER}/tmp
local_tmp  = /tmp/.ansible-${USER}/tmp

[ssh_connection]
pipelining = True
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=30m -F ./ssh-{{ env }}.cfg
control_path = /tmp/ansible-%%r@%%h:%%p
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove *ssh_args* from the configuration file and use environment [ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-ssh-args). For example

```
ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS='-o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=30m -F ./ssh-apac.cfg' ansible-playbook -b -u test-user -e 'ansible_ssh_pass=****' -i inventory.yml provisioning/packages-playbook.yml
```

Comment: Thank you. That's help.